# Install php extensions on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

I have a Ubuntu 9.10 server. I have installed apache2 and php5 using the apt-get commands.

How does one install php extensions? Are there commands like apt-get to get them? Or should I manually look for the files on the php website and set them up in the php.ini?

More specifically, I need mcrypt, curl and gd.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-gd
```

If you need to check what is installed php-wise you can:

```
dpkg --list | grep php
```

EDIT: Removed sudo in the command above as it's not needed with dpkg --list.

Comment: no need for sudo when doing: dpkg --list ;)

Comment: + restart apache

Comment: Some extensions will leave an ini file in `/etc/php5/conf.d` that needs to be merged into the main ini. To do this you normally use `php5enmod` and `php5dismod` to enable and disable the extension's config. For example, if I need to enable the MongoDB extension I would use `php5enmod mongo`.

Using these commands means you never have to mess with sym links or have to manually edit your main ini.

Comment: this works for ubuntu 13.04, with a clean install. if you are trying to get mongo working, you should install the mongo dependencies first.

Comment: @Eno do you do a normal install eg sudo apt-get php5-gd then do sudo php5enmod php5-gd for example??? IF not, could you elaborate on the correct procedure? Thanks.

Comment: nb. you might also need to `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` (for me curl and gd were enabled automatically on install but mcrypt wasn't)

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, you can review the available PHP extensions on your Debian/Ubuntu system by:

```
apt-cache search php|egrep ^php5-
```